# Adjoining a square root of the discriminant of an irreducible cubic.

Tags: galois-theory

Here is an exercise.

> Let $\delta$ be a square root of the discriminant of $P$, an irreducible cubic polynomial over a field $K$ with characteristic not equal to 2. Show that $P$ is irreducible over $K(\delta)$.

This is what I think: $\delta^2\in K$ so $[K(\delta):K]\le 2$. But if $P$ is not irreducible over $K(\delta)$ then it must have a root $a$ in it since P is cubic. Then $[K(a):K]=3$ since $P$ must be a constant multiple of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$. But also $K(a)\in K(\delta)$ but $[K(a):K]>[K(\delta):K]$. Contradiction.

But nowhere have I used the condition that $char K\neq 2$. Can someone point what I have done wrong, or is the condition really unnecessary? Thanks!

Comment: In a finite field of characteristic 2 every element is already a square, so adding the square root of the discriminant in fact changes nothing.

Comment: @Mark That's not true. Is $t$ a square in $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in one variable?

Comment: @AlexB. I specified a finite field.

Answer (score 0):

For $\operatorname{char}(K) = 2$, the discriminant of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is $(ab+c)^2$, so the statement is still true, so the assumption is not necessary.